# Can't connect to socket.io server from Node JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I've got a socket.io server running on Node JS listening for messages. I now need to start another Node JS script (my client) which will send messages to the server, that's at a specific URL and port.

I'm passing my URL into the `connect` function but am getting the error:

```
TypeError: io.connect is not a function
```

How can I pass my URL to connect to into this. My script is:

```js
const io = require('socket.io');

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.send('hello') // send to server from running JS script
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to initiate a socket.io connection from node.js, you need the [client-side library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) which would be:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client')
```

And, of course, you have to install that library.

Comment: @RyanH - Did this answer your question?